# How can I mimic/simulate the GIMP's 'Pinch Distortion Filter' using OpenCV2 with python?

Tags: python, opencv

According to The Gimp's [documentation](https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-whirl-pinch.html), this filter works straightforward, using an ammount value as input, I can do distortions in any image like this, for example:

The **original** and the **filtered**:

[image: Original] --->
[image]

So, my challenge now, is reproduce (don't need to be exactly, just similar) this behavior using Python and OpenCV. As you can see bellow, I reached the following stub until now:

```
import cv2
import numpy
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')

# Do some processing before

x_size = 240
y_size = 320
map_y=numpy.zeros((x_size,y_size),dtype=numpy.float32)
map_x=numpy.zeros((x_size,y_size),dtype=numpy.float32)

cv2.remap(img, map_x, map_y , cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', img)
```

However, now I'm unsure if using `remap` function is a good way, and in this case, neither what kind of map I should use. How can I complete it? Is there some alternatives to perform this task?